# Group by the specific day, month, and year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follow, now I use the `group by date` and it only group my data based on the year. I want to group the data based on the specific day, month, and year.

Do you know how we can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
group by  day(`date`),month(`date`),year(`date`)
```

[Check](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) for more info